# How can I connect two quad spheres?

Tags: modeling

I have been working on a bird. I created the body and head with two quad spheres. Now, I need to connect them to create the neck.

I deleted the faces highlighted in orange in the first image below. I then selected four vertices at a time and used "f" to fill with faces. See the second image.

I am certain that this isn't the correct way to connect the two spheres to make the neck. The faces I am creating with the fills are not flat. The vertices aren't lines up in a single plane.
(If I try to subdivide these faces, I get some weird results.)

How can I connect the body and the head of the bird?

Am I better off just extruding the neck from the body, and then extruding/creating the head from the neck geometry?

[image]

Comment: My answer was going to be pretty much the same as @moonboots. But I would add.. look at the general form.. it would make sense to tilt the ovoid that is the head so its equator  is roughly in line with the beak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've selected all these faces it would have been faster to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*, or right click *LoopTools > Bridge* (in that case you need to enable the *LoopTools* addon). Also, I'm not sure why you want your faces to be flat.

[image]

Your result is not perfect but:

- Maybe you should work with a bit less polygons.
- You could have extruded the faces of the body to make the neck then extrude again to make the head. If you want to make the neck more cylindric, select the faces you plan to extrude and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and drag (*To Sphere*), it will make the selection rounder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the Bridge Edge Loops.  I will look into that. (There is so much to learn.) After I posted this, I realized that I could have used a cylinder for the neck. That would have been round as opposed to the flat faces that just connecting it would have done.

Comment: you can make the base rounder if you select the edge loop and press Alt Shift S, then when you'll extrude it will make a cylinder

Comment: I extruded the neck from the body and connected it to a new simpler quad sphere for the head.   https://imgur.com/a/EhG5SzJ

Comment: it seems to work better, maybe don't work with so many faces at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make an edge loop into a circular shape is to use the Loop Tools addon. Simply go into preferences > add-ons, and type 'loop' in the search field. When the Loop Tools shows up, enable it via the checkbox. Now in the 3d viewport, make a loop selection, right-click and at / near the top of the contextual menu, within the *Loop Tools* menu, select 'Circle' and voila! The bonus here is that there are additional options in the lower left redo panel! Using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> gives a more organic feel as the circular shape 'evolves' as you mouse drag. But sometimes it doesn't give correct circular results. In this case though, moonboots suggestion would work, as you wouldn't want a perfect circle.

Comment: Thanks for those instructions (especially the right-click menu). I read about that on another post. I added it through the Preferences; but, the other post didn't say how to get to it to use it. I'll try that.